# Does sqoop acquire any locks when importing from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, locking, hdfs, sqoop

I'm using sqoop to import from SQL Server into HDFS.  I'm wondering if any locks are acquired on the table I'm importing from, and if so, is there a way to do the equivalent of `WITH(NOLOCK)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop is issuing usual select queries, so it does the same locks as the query would. No extra additional locking is performed by Sqoop.

We've recently improved build-in Microsoft SQL Connector to support table hints, please check out [SQOOP-724](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-724). We're currently working on getting new version 1.4.3, that will contain this feature.

Comment: Thanks, Jarcec - both for your answer here and on the sqoop-user list where I posted the same question :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as per SQOOP-724.

Here, a sample also included

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sqoop-user/201302.mbox/%3CCAL=o-uTG3Pwrtd+brF9q+b6zEZUSnJ9Z35BYRrsvNr1gi1pxXA@mail.gmail.com%3E